# Restoring sharepoint 2010 subsite backup in sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have taken a back up of sharepoint 2010 site using central admin & have .cmp file.

Now I would like to restore the site in a sharepint 2013 site.

ie, I want to import this site to a 2013 subsite.

Is it possible to restore 2010 site back up to 2013 site?

Please share your thoughts.

Regards

Vishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please lookup [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62236/restore-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-to-sharepoint-2013) as the answer is pointing out, it doesn't work that way. Try to use Move-SPSite to move your site into a seperate database. That way you could upgrade that database to SP2013.

If you're talking about an SPWeb there seems to be an other solution described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57229/is-it-possible-to-copy-sp-web-from-2010-to-2013).